# What is the meaning of this Russian profanity?

Tags: словоупотребление, выражения, сленг, мат

I am a new learner in the Russian language, and I don't know the rules of this exchange. But recently I came across this saying (I am sorry in advance for the phrase): "ёпта мохнатка":

> Яже тебе уже писал. Ты же РУССКИЙ так что пиши по русски епта мохнатка

I tried, of course, googling it, but it wasn't very informative on the usage. I learned that "ёпта" is an expression like "damn" in English, sort of a cuss word. While "мохнатка" is a slang word for the female reproductive organ, to put it like this :).

So combining both, you get something like "damn p***y," but I was just curious when it is used? Or why would someone say that?

Is it sort of like "a coward?"

Comment: Hi and welcome to Russian.SE! Could you please share with us the context where you have encountered this phrase? Thanks!

Comment: The original one I encountered in VK and was just that phrase written. Then I went to Twitter to find more. I'm just quoting the person: "Яже тебе уже писал. Ты же РУССКИЙ так что пиши по русски епта мохнатка". I could not make sense of it, so I headed here :)

Comment: Firstly, this rude sentence (not about this мохнатка), but in the essence of this and manner and the orthography - showed us the author of this sentence a some primite villager, peasant, redneck, villein... :> the Yeti from woods... and swamps.. __ ёпта - the "mat", adverb; very rude and, additionally, shortness and incorrect gramatical form... which show mb - autor not able to say full form.. ___"мохнатка" - provincialism, primitivism, rare village's, country slang... mb - forest slang :>
______
Ты же РУССКИЙ, так что пиши по-русски, ёпта, - "мохнатка"; - grammatically correct sentence...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Ёпта* is a lax rendition of *ёб твою мать* (literally, "(I) fucked your mother"), which can serve as an interjection or a filler phrase in quite a variety of cases.

"Ёпта мохнатка" is a colorful variation on this theme. It's a filler phrase which might be translated as "for fuck's sake" or "fuck me".

It's a set phrase which has gained some traction in online communities and might or might not survive the next year.

The original phrase means: "I've written this to you already. You're Russian, so write in Russian, for fuck's sake"

Comment: Thank you so much! It really helped

Comment: I should add that it doesn't really sound quite as aggressive as for fuck's sake, it quirky and kind of comedic. You wouldn't use it if you were serious or very angry, it could even conceivably soften your tone from aggressive to more friendly.

Comment: @Curiosity so maybe use it between friends or when you have close relationships so as to not offend them?

Comment: Pretty much! As long as profanity is acceptable in that social circle.

Comment: @MaybelineLee or rather - as a general rule with profanities -  don't use it at all unless you are really sure what you are doing. To some this kind of "soft" profanity may sound silly and they will prefer a "real" swearword or none at all. There are some euphemism that are more or less mainstream now, this one  really isn't. Just as Quassnoi said  "[it] might or might not survive the next year"

Comment: @YaroslavFyodorov I guess it applied everywhere to not use profanities without knowing their meaning. I was just curious as I couldn't find anything on the internet regarding this phrase. But I guess new slangs appear every day. Thank you for your comment :)

Comment: @MaybelineLee I didn't mean to say: Don't swear. It's a personal choice. I was specifically referring to "maybe use it between friends". I would be very surprised to hear this specific expression from anyone in my vicinity, because it carries a very specific vibe (which I can't pinpoint at the moment).

Comment: @YaroslavFyodorov what I meant was to not use swear words in a language you don’t fully understand their meanings as it may cause problems :). But if you can pinpoint the vibe from this expression later let me know, I’m curious.

Comment: It just sounds working class kind of swear. Educated people don’t cuss like this

Comment: @Aksakalalmostsurelybinary: educated people say _ёб вашу мать_.

Comment: @Quassnoi or  [Настоящий старый питерский интеллигент никогда не скажет: "## вашу мать! ", он скажет: "Да я вам в отцы гожусь! ".
Анекдот взят с сайта anekdotov.me](https://anekdotov.me/nacionalnosti/7871-nastoyashhij-staryj-piterskij-intelligent-nikogda.html) :)

Answer (score 2):

To add to other users' extensive answers, I would note that the syntactic relationship of the profane phrase to the rest of the sentence is not clear and might as well be absent.

A *lot* of Russian profane structures are not *per se* parts of the sentence — they are discourse markers. In such cases, they relate to the whole sentence, rather than any part of it, and make up a commentary on the emotional perception of the situation as a whole. Thereby it is, as per @Quassnoi, a colourful rendition of "for fuck's sake" and doesn't directly characterise you personally (though people may take offense at that).

Comment: Thank you for your input. Apparently, people are getting creative at inventing new phrases each day :)

Answer (score 0):

This means, literally, "fuck you, cunt".

The entire phrase you are citing has multiple orthographic errors, by the way.

Comment: So it has a strong negative connotation towards someone you don’t like?

Comment: @Maybeline Lee ,  No, no, and no. Curiosity gave the right answer

Comment: @Elena ok so a lighthearted swear to your friend. Because all of these answers are confusing me a bit. If you could pinpoint the vibe this phrase gives, it would be helpful

Comment: @MaybelineLee "I've already said to you. You are RUSSIAN, so write in Russian, fuck your mother, cunt."

Comment: @MaybelineLee it displays 1. Irritation sentiment, disappointment 2. Use of criminal, ruddest  language. 3. The contraction type shows this kind of speech is common for them. 4. Total disrespect, attempt to "test" your patience and humiliate. 5. Explosive, aggressive character. The person would possibly not tolerate this kind of speech reflected to them and in real life could resort to violence. Maybe this already indicates they are ready to use violence. If you are a male, using "cunt" to you is especially humilating. I would stop any contact with such person immediately

Comment: @Anixx thank you for your comment. I'm just confused because some others before were hinting at a more playful vibe than this strong character you are describing. But I'll take your words into consideration.

Comment: @MaybelineLee I do not see, how the word мохнатка addressed to another person can be playful. It is not some garbage word placeholder that can be addressed into air, like "shit!". It is a rather rare word, which can indicate the person is an expert at profanities. It is an anatomical word, literally referring to "a female organ with public hair" and definitely addressed to the addressee of the phrase.

Comment: @MaybelineLee I also see some kind of Nationalist/Racist attitude as if the author was demanding the addressee to "behave like a Russian" after the addressee in their eyes declared themselves Russian. These demands to behave the way one once called oneself and satisfy the "rank" is also typical to Russian criminals. It looks like in the eyes of the author the addressee failed to suit their declared status and should be demoted to the worst caste (which is equal to passive homosexuals).

Comment: @Maybeline Lee Different people treat obscene speech differently. Therefore, the reaction is different. Anixx is right about one thing. The author of that obscene phrase writes with grammatical errors. This is a simple uneducated guy. For him, obscene speech is absolutely natural (natural as breathing). He will be extremely surprised if he hears the opinion that his speech is offensive and unfriendly, because it contains the words "fuc" and "pussy".

Comment: @Elena I disagree. мохнатка is not the same as English pussy. It is in fact, a rare word. It cannot be just a figure of speech. I agree, the guy is uneducated, but he speaks with criminal manners (which is indicated with the word епта instead of say a longer version ебать твою мать which would be even less offensive). Епта is something like the language the criminals speak to their victims and people they disrespect. Also, such people are usually very CAUTIOUS about obscene speech, and never use it between themselves.

Comment: @Elena @\Anixx I'm not generally interested in the guy who says "speak in Russian". He was just an example I stumbled upon when searching just for ёпта мохнатка and I was trying to understand what it meant. My first contact with this particular phrase was at VK, where this guy had only posted "ёпта мохнатка" and I just got curious to know what it meant. But I get it, and it's offensive and a very brute thing to say out loud. Maybe it's a new phrase youngsters use these days who knows. But thank you for your clarifications

Comment: @Anixx Нave you read  Quassnoi's answer? 'It's a set phrase which has gained some traction in online communities and might or might not survive the next year'. All your logical construction is based on the thesis 'this phrase is unusual, it is used only by criminals who want to humiliate the victim. Criminals do not use obscene language when communicating with equals.' And if Quassnoi' is right and this phrase has become common for the Internet community in the last year?

Comment: "cunt" - "мохнатка" not so rude. this is not a "mat". But this is a very country blockish primitive peasant's style :> also some childish primitive connotation... 
Well - the autor (of sentence), probably, drool usually... :> and lives in a tree
______
"cunt" - пизда.